# Update record where category_id=0

Tags: php, cakephp

I set category_id to 0 and category id is auto increment. so I update this record in cakephp then cakephp will insert this record insted of update this record.

```
$this->Category->id=$id;
$this->Category->save($this->data);
```

Pls help me...

Comment: Make sure you've set the id for record or passing the id with record.

Comment: I pass id=0 and id is auto increment in database table. In this case error occurs other wise work fine.

Comment: If I am not understanding wrong, you should not update auto increment column. Why would you want to do such thing ?

Comment: I do not update auto increment column but i update category_name based on category_id.

Comment: please add the $this->data values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### An Id of 0 is invalid

There's an [implicit assumption](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.4.2/lib/Cake/Model/Model.php#L3375) with CakePHP that all identifiers are truthy:

```
/**
 * Returns the current record's ID
 *
 * @param integer $list Index on which the composed ID is located
 * @return mixed The ID of the current record, false if no ID
 */
public function getID($list = 0) {
    if (empty($this->id) || ...) {
        return false;
    }
    ...
```

as such trying to save with an id of 0 will not work, causing Cake to attempt an insert even if a row exists with that falsey id.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understand you correctly, but if you want to update ALL records WHERE category_id=0 then this code would be effecient:

```
$this->Category->updateAll(
    $this->data,
    array('Category.category_id' => 0)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Cakephp will update record if id is greater then 0 other wise it insert new record. So try to change id 0 to greater than 0.
Try this.